# где можно разместить телеграм бота с небольшой базой данных?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, hosting, python-telegram-bot

Встал такой вопрос.У бота есть небольшая база данных в виде текстового файла который формируют из вне и потом бот в него заглядывает и отвечает информацией в ответ.Знаю что на хостингах можно размещать ботов.Но как быть с текстовым файлом.Он по сути при помощи скрипта закачивается с дропбокса. Физический сервер люди снять не могут.Да и дорого для одного бота.На хостинг где сайт проблематично,сложная и долгая комуникация с сотрудниками которые держат бота.И еще вопрос: нужно ли брать деньги за поддержку бота помесячно?если да то какая сумма если например свой сервак предоставлять?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какой хостинг

Большинство дешёвых дают вам просто какой либо дистрибутив линукс и +- гигабайт памяти (хотя смотря как настроите), и на такой хостинг можно закидывать любые файлы и запускать любые скрипты

По сути вы арендуете не физический, а виртуальный сервер, за 100-200 рублей вам вполне хватит мощностей на первое время

Comment: в том то и дело люди платить не могут.а если и могут то зачем мне эти деньги терять?я ведь могу на своем сервере запускать  @Швеев Алексей

Comment: @Sergey У вас есть свой сервер?

Comment: @Sergey А зачем вам тогда нужен хостинг?

Comment: ну люди не могут платить даже и копейки.бюджет!Есть у меня возможность размещать,но сколько брать и от чего зависит цена @Швеев Алексей

Comment: @Sergey А, вы продаёте свой сервер?

Comment: продаю не продаю это не важно вопрос в другом @Швеев Алексей

Comment: @Sergey Хорошо, ещё раз
Вы хотите разместить бота на хостинге, однако у вас нулевой бюджет, верно?

Comment: да. денег нет.и как я понимаю бесплатных виртуальных хостингов нет. @Швеев Алексей

Comment: @Sergey На самом деле возможно существуют сервисы с огромными ограничениями, которые позволяют запускать простые скрипты 24/7, но как вы верно подметили БД в большинстве из них вы вряд ли сделаете. Если вы подождёте, то я возможно смогу найти подходящий для вас вариант, если откопаю название хостинга (я забыл )

Comment: @Sergey Не нашёл тот сервис, сори) Можешь поискать сам, рекомендую по англоязычному интернету, там меньше сайтов заблокировано, удачи)